# How does the symfony groups validation work

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I am little bit confused regarding symfony group validation.

Suppose i have this code

```
 * @NotBlank(groups={"A", "B", "C"})
 */
private $description;
```

When i submit the form then i am manually inject groups like this

`$this->validator->validate($object, groups={"F", "A","C"})`

Now i want to know how symfony will do validation

1. Does symfony check that all the groups ie, `F,A,C` SHOULD MATCHED WITH `A,B,C` OR it checks if any groups from `F,A,C` is present in defined gorup'A,B,C'. So if any item macthes then it do the validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [validate() method signature](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Validator.php), you may understand that you should not think of the `$groups` parameter it as a parameter that allows you to inject validation groups.

It's used to ask your validator to validate a given object **against** some groups of constraints.

**Example of use,**

```
/*
 * @NotBlank(groups={"A", "B"})
 */
private $property1;

/*
 * @NotBlank(groups={"C"})
 */
private $property2;

/*
 * @NotBlank(groups={"B"})
 */
private $property3;
```

Then,

```
$this->validator->validate($object, groups={"A", "C"})
```

will validate your `property1` & `property2` against the `NotBlank` constraint.

But when calling,

```
$this->validator->validate($object, groups={"A", "B"})
```

only `property1` & `property3` are validated againt the NotBlank constraint as `group C` isn't invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony lists all constraints from groups `F, A, C` and apply them on your data. If a constraint is in 2 or more groups, it will be applied only once.

So, about your example, the NotBlank constraint on your $description field should be applied.